# As a web developer what is my new Zealand visa Industry?

Tags: visas, new-zealand, working-holiday

I am applying for a New Zealand working holiday visa, filling the form I was asked occupation, which I found, and industry, which I didn't.

I found my occupation of web developer [here](http://glossary.immigration.govt.nz/FullOccupationalList.htm).

But I can't really find any industry that fits Web developer in [this list](http://glossary.immigration.govt.nz/FullIndustryList.htm).

I'm trying [this link](http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/0/ACC2F9615290D8EECA25697E0018FAF6?opendocument) since the industry classification seems to be the same one for Australia than New Zealand.

Can you help me choose and adequate industry?

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to answer it.  The industry depends on your employer.  For example, if you work for a car rental company, you should choose L774100, motor vehicle hiring.

Comment: @phoog I don't understand why this was closed. I said my occupation is web developer. In fact in the links I provided within the questions itself, I found the answer. I am asking what industry should I choose if I'm a web developer for a specific visa, the answer is L783400. It doesn't get more specific than that :)

Comment: @phoog I added some further clarifications, maybe it helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it!

L783400 Computer Consultancy Services

It fits perfectly.